# Generate certificate on dev machine and copy to prod?

Tags: lets-encrypt

I want to use Let's Encrypt to create a certificate for my website. I have the client installed locally on my dev machine and would like to generate the cert and move it.

For stand-alone webserver installation, the Let's Encrypt documentation says I must specify the path to the web root. But that path doesn't exist locally.

Is it possible to generate the cert locally? Or should I attempt to install let's encrypt on the host?

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. Can you copy this into an answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LE needs to connect to the IP your domain points to in order to completes its challenge/response domain verification. In order for this to work, you'll need to modify your DNS to point to your Dev server, which I would guess you'd like to avoid doing? :)

Comment: Technically, LE supports DNS based challenge/response now which wouldn't necessarily require repointing the web server's DNS record. http://serverfault.com/questions/750902/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-dns-challenge-validation

Comment: Ahh, interesting. I knew this was in the works, but hadn't heard that it was implemented yet.

Comment: Yeah, it's still pretty darn new.