# Let's Encrypt Certbot DNS 01 Challenge

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm hosting my own webserver and currently don't use port 80 because my ISP has blocked it. But I found out that my ISP doesn't actually block port 443, so I attempted to use Certbot on my domain with a txt record (DNS 01 Challenge I believe it is called). I followed the guide [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/750902/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-dns-challenge-validation), and I tried the manual plugin which seemed to work. the output it gave was promising, unfortunately I have not kept it. There were definitely no error messages and the certificate was generated. However, I'm not sure how I would configure apache to use this certificate (please correct me if my words don't make any sense, this whole thing was mostly a learning experience).

So my question is, how would I configure my website to use HTTPS now that I have a certificate from letsencrypt?

Any help is highly appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: It depends on which webserver you are using...

Answer (score 0):

At this page you can find a tool that generates a sample SSL configuration for a whole bunch of webservers: https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

You can use its output as an help to get started