# Letsencrypt for all subdomains *.example.com

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'd like to obtain one certificate working for all my subdomains `*.example.com`.

This works:

```
certbot-auto certonly --webroot --webroot-path /home/www/example/ --domain example.com 
                                --domain www.example.com --email certbot@example.com
```

but this (with  `*.`):

```
certbot-auto certonly --webroot --webroot-path /home/www/example/ --domain example.com 
                                --domain *.example.com --email certbot@example.com
```

fails with:

> Obtaining a new certificate
>   Performing the following challenges:
>   Client with the currently selected authenticator does not support any combination of challenges that will satisfy the CA. You may need to use an authenticator plugin that can do challenges over DNS.

**How to use `certbot-auto` to generate a certificate for `*.example.com`?**

Comment: You need an authenticator plugin that can do challenges over DNS.

Comment: Thanks @GeraldSchneider but I don't really understand fully the context of this other question. Do you think you could post an answer showing how to do it in the context of my question? I think it might be interesting on its own here with a simple question wording "how to use letsencrypt with *.example.com", rather than this other question which seems less obvious "how to use DNS challenge validation" for future readers.

Comment: What for? For wildcard domains [you need DNS challenge validation](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#does-let-s-encrypt-issue-wildcard-certificates). DNS challenge validation is explained in detail in the linked question and answers (apart from the official documentation). Once your question is closed as a duplicate there is no need for further explanations, because it is obvious that the existing question also answers yours.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the solution is to use DNS challenge validation, like here: [How to use Let's Encrypt DNS-01 challenge validation?](https://serverfault.com/questions/750902/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-dns-challenge-validation/812038#812038).

First, remove your previous certificate (if needed) with the following command:

```
certbot-auto delete 
# Or for newer versions
certbot --cert-name example.com # Name you can find in /etc/letsencrypt/live directory
```

Then generate a new certificate with a DNS challenge:

```
certbot-auto -d *.example.com -d example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
# Or for newer versions
certbot -d *.example.com -d example.com --manual --preferred-challenges dns certonly
```

Then copy/paste the TXT challenge, into your DNS settings, something like:

```
_acme-challenge.example.com TXT Chs768564536576SDGdG6SQDYTZAEq
```

Restart Apache/nginx if needed, and it works.

PS: in my case, no installation of an authenticator plugin was needed (is it probably installed out of the box?)

Important notice: to validate the wildcard domain, you **must** use the DNS validation, you can however validate many subdomains at a time using many times the `-d` option.

Comment: I'll add if your DNS Server isn't on the supported list for dns-api, you can delegate the `_acme-challenge` record to them, for example.

`_acme-challenge IN CNAME example.com.example.net`

see https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dns-providers-who-easily-integrate-with-lets-encrypt-dns-validation/86438 for the list

Comment: Is The certificate autorenewed or I must renew it every X days?