# Issue valid HTTPS certificates for intranet subdomains with letsencrypt

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, https, internal-dns, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to provide secure services on my home intranet. Up to now I've used self-signed certificates with a made-up domain `example.foo`, with a subdomain for my separate systems (e.g. `srv1.example.foo`). These domains are defined on my local DNS server.

Now I've bought the domain `example.com`, but have no plans on providing any public services. I also have a VPS with static IPs to point `example.com` to.

I hope to create a wildcard letsencrypt certificate for `*.example.com` to use for my intranet systems. To separate local systems from anything public, I'd define a subdomain on my local DNS, which should not be resolved on public DNS servers (e.g. `*.local.example.com`). Thus have local intranet systems use names like `srv1.local.example.com`.

Is this setup feasible?

Can I create such a certificate on my VPS for `*.example.com` and secure intranet services with the generated certificate. Have my local DNS server resolve domains like `srv1.local.example.com` to private IPs and not expose any private IPs or domains to the public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I create such a certificate on my VPS for *.example.com and secure intranet services with the generated certificate.

Yes, but it's a strange way of doing it. It doesn't make automation easy.

I would run certbot (or whatever tool you use) on the *actual* system that needs the certificate, or some server inside your network where the system that needs it can grab it.

Use [dns challenge authentication](https://serverfault.com/questions/750902/how-to-use-lets-encrypt-dns-challenge-validation) to validate control over the domain. This requires an external DNS provider that has API, e.g., Route53, Cloudflare, Azure, or a multitude of others.

You don't need any pbulic dns records except the txt records used for validating ownership.

Comment: Right, so I obviously need to put more research into how letsencrypt allows you to create certificates. Thank you for your response! I'm under the impression, that the best practice in this case would be to look into the DNS challenge authentication and issue the certificate from an internal server - correct?

Comment: I would argue so. Less exposure of secrets, less copying, easier to automate potentially.

Comment: The first **yes** (as OP ask the question) is wrong! You can't use wildcard on more than one level.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Good catch, didn't notice the two levels.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create wildcard certificate for `*.example.com` and use it for `s1.sd.example.com`. This is how the certificates work. If you want to create wildcard certificate for `s1.sd.example.com` it must be for `*.sd.example.com`

Comment: With letsencrypt and the aforementioned dns challenge, i should be able to create wildcard certificates for both `*.example.com` and `*.local.example.com`, right? With this I reveal that there are more hosts as subdomains of `local.example.com` (e.g. `srv1.local.example.com`, but all can get valid certificates.

Comment: @emma.makes, correct. FOr `h1.d1.example.com`, `h2.d1...` you should use `*.d1.example.com`